# How to programmatically change the style of a single word of an HTML paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to programmatically change the style of a single word of an HTML paragraph

```js
let textToSearch = "testing"

let beforeNode = document.createElement('p');
let afterNode = document.createElement('p');

let highlightedSpan = document.createElement('span')
highlightedSpan.innerHTML = textToSearch;
highlightedSpan.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
let newPar = document.createElement('p');
newPar.appendChild(highlightedSpan);

document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach((par) => {
  let cont = par.textContent;
  let startingPos = cont.indexOf(textToSearch)
  console.log(startingPos)
  if (startingPos !== -1) {
    let firstPart = cont.slice(0, startingPos - 1)
    let thirdPart = cont.slice(startingPos + textToSearch.length, cont.length - 1)
    beforeNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstPart))
    afterNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(thirdPart))
    par.replaceWith(beforeNode, highlightedSpan, afterNode)
  }
})
```

```html
<p> A complete text for testing purposes</p>
```

I get this output:

[image]

But I would like to understand if there is a visually better (now the text content is visually spread in three lines), cleaner way to change the style of a single word of an HTML paragraph

Comment: Often highlighting is done by span rather than p. Inserting a new paragraph (well, in fact, 2) seems to mess the semantics. Is there a reason for paragraph rather than span?

Comment: @AHaworth no specific reasons. Just trying to highlight single words . But here I used a span element : `let highlightedSpan = document.createElement('span')` . What I would like to do is to get rid of the other two TextNodes, and just programmatically (with JavaScript) insert <span> or <mark> elements to highlighted the specific word

Comment: What does getting rid of the text nodes mean?

Comment: @AHaworth I wanted to say that I don't like my solution because of the use of beforeNode and afterNode.

Comment: The answer from @tacoshy seems to be fine - does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SImply use regex to replace the word with a word wrapped in a span:

```js
const BODY = document.body;
BODY.innerHTML = BODY.innerHTML.replace('testing', `<span>testing</span>`);
```

```css
span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p> A complete text for testing purposes</p>
```

Comment: Thank you @tacoshy . Simple, clean and effective

Comment: If you want to highlight the word for semantic reason, you can also use the `<mark>` tag. If it's just for a matter of styling, `<span>` is the way to go.

Comment: @tacoshy What could be the reasons why with this code : ```BODY.innerHTML = BODY.innerHTML.replace(textToSearch, `<span style='background-color:yellow;'>${word}</span>`); ```  the word is NOT always highlighted ?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question!

Comment: @tacoshy I've been "testing"/using that line of code in real webpages. And I realized that it does not always highlight the word(s). And it is strange to me, because `BODY.innerHTML.replace` should be general enough

Comment: I would need to see a specific case where it fails to see how the issue is produced. Is the span applied correctly?

Comment: example: https://wxwidgets.org/ . I successfully highlighted  the text : " make their existing wxWidgets applications access modern icon sets with limited effort." .  But I'm not able to highlight, for example, the text : " Also fix entering dates in wxGenericDatePicker in "nb_NO" and other locales using months names in short date format."